# Map object query over ignite

Tags: sql, ignite

I am a beginner at Ignıte. I am doing a sample app in order to measure query times of it.

So the key in the cache is String, value is Map. One of the field in value Map is "order_item_subtotal" so the query is like:

```
select * from Map where order_item_subtotal>400
```

And the sample code is:

```
Ignite ignite= Ignition.ignite();
IgniteCache<String, Map<String, Object>> dummyCache= ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);
Map<String,Map<String, Object>> bufferMap=new HashMap<String,Map<String, Object>>();

int i=0;
for (String jsonStr : jsonStrs) {
    if(i%1000==0){
        dummyCache.putAll(bufferMap);
        bufferMap.clear();
    }
    Map data=mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Map.class);
    bufferMap.put(data.get("order_item_id").toString(), data);
    i++;
}

SqlFieldsQuery asd=new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from Map where order_item_subtotal>400");

List<List<?>> result=  dummyCache.query(asd).getAll();
```

But the result is always "[]", means empty.  And there is no error or exceptions.

What am I missing here? any ideas?

PS: sample data below

```
{order_item_id=99, order_item_order_id=37, order_item_product_id=365, order_item_quantity=1, order_item_subtotal=59.9900016784668, order_item_product_price=59.9900016784668, product_id=365, product_category_id=17, product_name=Perfect Fitness Perfect Rip Deck, product_description=, product_price=59.9900016784668, product_image=http://images.acmesports.sports/Perfect+Fitness+Perfect+Rip+Deck}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported. You should use a simple POJO class instead of a map to make it work.

Note that Ignite will store data in binary format and will not deserialize objects when running queries. So you still don't need to deploy class definitions on server node. Please refer to this page for more details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller

Comment: Seems like that :( Cases like mine , need expanding data structures in runtime and lack of ability to query expanding data is definitely a problem that needs to be fixed. Thx

Comment: @Neron, you can change the schema dynamically if binary format is used (it's the default one): https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller. You can even use `BinaryObjectBuilder` and don't have any class definitions at all. The only current limitation is that SQL schema is still static, i.e. you if you add a field you can't use it in a query or index it. This will be addressed in future releases.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was at that point too :) this also makes storage as insensitive to polymorphism when we try to query it